# HDIV validation change generic error message for field

Tags: java, spring, hdiv

I'm trying to change the generic hdiv validation message coming from MessageResources.properties:

```
hdiv.editable.error={0} has not allowed characters
```

I can override the message in my own messages.properties with:

```
hdiv.editable.error = {0} contains bla bla
```

Is there a way I can do `hdiv.editable.bean.property` or something similar so that I can have field specific error messages?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that at the moment. We hope to develop that feature in the future.

Regards,

Fernando Lozano (HDIV Team)

Comment: Hi, cheers for that, I'll be looking forward to it. For now I've made all HDIV error messages the same and that currently works for our case. Thanks again.